# simple_form association accesses record that user doesn't have access rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, cancan

I have a Rails 4 App that has a simple association model.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :opportunities
has_many :customers
has_many :accounts
```

**opportunity.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :account
```

**customer.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :account
```

**account.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :opportunities, dependent: :destroy 
has_many :customers, dependent: :destroy
```

Here's the customer controller

```
def index
  @customers = Customer.accessible_by(current_ability)
end

def show
  @customers = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @customer.user = current_user
  authorize! :show, @customer
end

def new
  @customer = Customer.new
  @customer.user = current_user
  authorize! :new, @customer
end

def edit
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @customer.user = current_user
  authorize! :edit, @customer
end
```

I have CanCan for ability control;

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    end
    can :manage, Account, user_id: user.id
    can :manage, Opportunity, user_id: user.id
    can :manage, Customer, user_id: user.id
  end
end
```

I'm using simple_form to add account associations to customers.

```
<%=f.association :account,:label => 'Customer Account Name', label_method: :account_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: '-- Select One --' %>
```

The problem is the association tag seems to be able to access all accounts in the database not just those associated to the user. I can't work it out the association tag seems to ignore any restrictions.

Gem Versions
`rails`, `4.0.4`
`simple_form`, `3.0.2`
"cancan"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default simple form will just include all items for an association. In order to limit the options in the dropdown you'll want to set the `collection` attribute like so and pass in only the records the user can access, for example:

```
<%= f.association :account, :label => 'Customer Account Name', label_method: :account_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: '-- Select One --', collection: Account.accessible_by(current_ability) %>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Mario, that worked! I would upvote but I'm lacking in "reputation", I wonder though if there's a way to secure this in the controller too?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an automatic/magical way to do it, but you could do it manually by calling: `authorize! :manage, @account` You'll need to do a lookup on the account and populate `@account` with it.